# Get Similar keys/values from 2 different nested structs in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have 2 nested structs, as below.

```
%Test.Identities.MetaDetails{
  browser_name: "Chrome",
  browser_version: "108.0.0",
  confidence: %Test.Identities.MetaDetails.Confidence{
    score: 0.9989648033126294
  },
  device: "Other",
  first_seen_at: %Test.Identities.MetaDetails.SeenAt{
    global: ~U[2022-11-25 14:56:09Z],
    subscription: ~U[2022-11-30 14:24:49Z]
  },
  incognito: true,
  ip: "206.84.141.32",
  ip_location: %Test.Identities.MetaDetails.IpLocation{
    accuracy_radius: 5.0,
    city: nil,
    continent: nil,
    country: nil,
    latitude: 33.7233,
    longitude: 73.0435,
    postal_code: "44000",
    subdivisions: [],
    timezone: "Asia/Karachi"
  },
  last_seen_at: %Test.Identities.MetaDetails.SeenAt{
    global: ~U[2022-12-13 11:52:24Z],
    subscription: ~U[2022-12-13 11:52:24Z]
  },
  meta: %Test.Identities.MetaDetails.Meta{
    version: "v1.1.1032+f754139d"
  },
  os: "Linux",
  os_version: nil,
  request_id: "1670933504035.XjTnVT",
  visitor_found: true,
  visitor_id: "nzpkWv3ggKJsgXPx97Z0"
}
```

I have 2 nested maps as above and both maps look mostly the same but they are different key values as well. I am trying to get what is matching in both nested maps.

Update:

The below solution works for maps only, I tested that with maps,s not structs, so sorry about this.

`for {k, v} <- m1, m2[k] == v, do: {k, v}` with this I can only get first-level maps.

Comment: Are they maps or structs in the first place? Structs do not implement `Enumerable` out of the box.

Comment: sorry yes, they are structs in the first place.

Comment: Then I fail to understand how `for {k, v} <- m1` ever works. Do these structs implement `Enumerable`? If so, do they implement `Access`?

Comment: Okay I take my words back, While testing I tested it over maps but you are right it won't work on structs.

Comment: I have updated my question thank you, please suggest something :)

Comment: If they are structs, their keys are defined during the compilation stage and they cannot be “similar,” you literally know whether they are equal or not. I do not follow what are you after.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question though. the struct has some keys let's say IP, and there is another struct that also has the key IP. If I compare both structs, the are exactly the same but not the IP key-value pair is the same in both. so What I want is: for everything else to leave IP key-value pair behind. so we will have a new map or struct or list or whatever, which will have every similar key value pair but not the IP.

I know you are saying

Comment: "you literally know whether they are equal or not" but how can you get equal values and leaving not equal ones, So A not equal to B. so is there anything literally similar in A and B,

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was not a oneliner, so I implemented it in [`estructura`](https://hexdocs.pm/estructura) library.

If you own the structs, the best way would be to add `use Estructura, enumerable: true` to each (the code would work without it, but slower, because it’d go through `Map.from_struct/1` and key lookups.)

[`Estructura.diff/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/estructura/Estructura.html#diff/3) is your friend. See usage examples in docs above, in your case to get only the overlap back, it’d be

```elixir
Estructura.diff(struct1, struct2, :overlap)
```

---

See the source code if you need the detailed answer to the question as code.